# How to tell Checkstyle to check all lines for linefeed / newline LF and not CRLF?

Tags: checkstyle

Is there a way to check if the file is using LFs only and no CRLFs or vice versa in checkstyle?

The only check which I have found is

```
NewlineAtEndOfFile
```

But I search for more as only at the end of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Only to supplement the Michal Kordas's good answer.*

Below is a slightly modified configuration, which will only match the first wrong newline and forbid also the Mac OS Line Endings (CR):

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="(?s:(\r\n|\r).*)"/>
    <property name="message" value="CRLF and CR line endings are prohibited, but this file uses them."/>
</module>
```

It has been posted by Michael Vorburger [in this discussion](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/893#issuecomment-113293027), so kudos for him - I've   posted it here for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing out-of-the box in Checkstyle yet. If you want to prohibit CRLF you can use the following config:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="\r\n"/>
    <property name="message" value="CRLF line endings are prohibited"/>
</module>
```

and this one to ban LFs:

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="(?<!\r)\n"/>
    <property name="message" value="LF line endings are prohibited"/>
</module>
```