# Forcing CRLF line separator in my project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, newline, separator

I want to ensure CRLF (Windows style) line separator in my project. I am checking a few alternatives, but not sure which one is the best for this.

**Desired Behavior:**

If a file is not CRLF, which IntelliJ IDEA shows at the bottom: 
[image]

**I want my maven profile, let's say *mvn clean install -P tests* to fail, saying something like "Invalid line separator, not CRLF"**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to cause the Maven build to fail due to invalid line separators in your project's files unless someone has created a plugin to do that. However, you can configure a code inspection in Intellij IDEA to fail for that reason. This is how you could provoke such a failure:

- Navigate to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Inconsistent Line Separators** then check the box for **Inconsistent Line Separators** and select **Error** from the drop list for **Severity**:

[image: IDEAsettings]

- Navigate to **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style** and specify the default line separator by selecting **Windows (\r\n)** from the **Line separator** drop list (if not already set).
- Invalidate the line separator setting for some open file in your project. For example: **File -> Line Separators -> CR - Classic Mac (\r)**
- Run an inspection on your project (**Analyze -> Inspect Code -> Whole Project**) and you should now get an error:

[image: IDEAinspection]

JetBrains has an [open bug ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78625#tab=Comments) to force compilation failure based on inspection errors, so this approach is not exactly what you were asking for. But in the absence of any Maven-based solution it might be best you can do. See the [Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html) documentation from JetBrains for more information.

One other possible approach is to look at [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/), another JetBrains tool for continuous integration. I haven't used it, but perhaps it allows you to configure failure when there are inspection errors (though from a quick look at their documentation I couldn't see how).

---

**Update:**

It looks like TeamCity might be worth a look after all. Its [documentation on Build Failure Conditions](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Failure+Conditions) states:

> When using code examining tools in your build, like code coverage,
>   duplicates finders, **inspections** and so on, your build generates
>   various numeric metrics. **For these metrics you can specify a threshold
>   which, when exceeded, will fail a build**.

Comment: thank you so much for your superb response buddy, I am going to take a look at it, but after a whole day of investigation yesterday, I am starting to suspect that my Jenkins changes CRLF files to LF! Any hint? Thank you so much

Comment: @stackman If you use Git I would think that is more likely than Jenkins to be relevant...but just a guess.

Comment: Any hint about how can I force CRLF always on Git?

Comment: Ty you are the king

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer stated:

> I don't think it is possible to cause the Maven build to fail due to invalid line separators in your project's files unless someone has created a plugin to do that.

But there *is* plugins for that. You can have a [checkstyle rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903412/how-to-tell-checkstyle-to-check-all-lines-for-linefeed-newline-lf-and-not-crlf):

```
<module name="RegexpMultiline">
    <property name="format" value="(?<!\r)\n"/>
    <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
    <property name="message" value="Invalid line separator, not CRLF"/>
</module>
```

And then configure build to use checkstyle plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
        <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
        <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
        <checkstyleRules>
            <module name="Checker">
                <module name="RegexpMultiline">
                    <property name="format" value="(?<!\r)\n"/>
                    <property name="maximum" value="0"/>
                    <property name="message" value="Invalid line separator, not CRLF"/>
                </module>
            </module>
        </checkstyleRules>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>checkstyle</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It [binds to "verify" phase by default](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html) that [should be already activated if you run install](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-core/lifecycles.html).

Comment: This approach is much better than the one I gave in my answer since it is independent of the IDE being used. See also [How to make Maven checking the source end-of-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15003871/2985643) which is not a duplicate, but relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Linux. When I commit with IDEA then I get my line separators converted to LF. When I do commit with SmartGit then all stays CRLF.

All I did - command:

`git config --global core.autocrlf false`

And now everything is fine.

Comment: The question is unrelated to version control. What git settings you use is a bit beside the point here, even though that too affects the situation.